# Xcode Analyzer warning - Dictionary value cannot be nil

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdictionary, analyzer

This question is one of curiosity.

I have two pre-existing Xcode projects which generate different Analyzer warnings.  I haven't been able to identify the setting difference.

```
NSString *someNilString;
NSDictionary *someDict=@{@"hi":someNilString};
```

(A more typical example is one where someNilString may or may not be nil - keeping it simple.)

If I run the Analyzer in one project, I get `Dictionary value cannot be nil` on the second line.  Same code in the second project, no message.  A new Xcode project (created in v6.2) generates the message, thus I believe that is (appropriately) the default.

I am curious where this setting may be.  I don't see an obvious setting for this in Build Settings.

Comment: Either `someNilString` is guaranteed to be nil, or `someNilString` is not an object pointer

Comment: Yes - I get why the warning appears, and of course the code above would crash.  I'm curious why the Analyzer warning appears in one project and not in the other.

Comment: What it says -- if `someNilString` is actually `nil` (and not simply a zero-length string) then you will have a runtime failure.

Comment: @HotLicks The OP knows that.  He wants to know the setting (if any) that affects the analyzer's behaviour.

Comment: The difference could be due to a difference in the target version.

Comment: Is one of these projects much older than the other? Like, one was created in a very recent version of Xcode (say 6+) and one in an older version?

Comment: Both projects have a Target of iOS 7.0.  The project displaying the warning was created in early 2011, in whatever version of Xcode that was current at the time.  I created that project so I'm familiar with its history.  The project not displaying the warning was created in late 2012 in Xcode 4.  I was not the original developer of the latter, so I don't know the early history as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that one project is using ARC and the other is not.

Under ARC, local variables are initialized to nil (zero).

Under manual memory management, a local variable contains whatever random value was left at that location in the stack at runtime.

So the ARC version is known to be nil when Xcode evaluates the someDict line.

Comment: I think you're on to something!  Both projects use ARC, but the one not throwing the Analyzer warning does have several classes with ARC explicitly disabled.  I'll run a few tests and report back, but I'll bet this is at least very related.